# Polling Azure queue returns Broken pipe

Tags: php, sockets, azure, long-polling, azure-storage-queues

When long polling Azure Queue Storage with **azure-sdk-for-php**, if my request are more than 30 seconds apart, the library dies with this error:

```
PHP Notice:  fwrite(): send of 277 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in ..../vendor/pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2/HTTP/Request2/SocketWrapper.php on line 188
```

If I set the **sleep** function to 30 seconds, everything goes great, but I'm making LOTS of requests that I don't need.

My workers code:

```
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

Class Worker_Task {

    public $queueRestProxy;

    public $servicesBuilder;

    public $connectionString;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connectionString = Config::get('azure.connection_string');
        $this->servicesBuilder = ServicesBuilder::getInstance();
        $this->queueRestProxy = $this->servicesBuilder->createQueueService($this->connectionString);
    }
    public function emails() {

        $this->write('Processing mails...');

        while(true) {

            $this->queueRestProxy = $this->servicesBuilder->createQueueService($this->connectionString);

            // Get message.
            $listMessagesResult = $this->queueRestProxy->listMessages("emails");
            $messages = $listMessagesResult->getQueueMessages();

            foreach($messages as $message) {

                // Process Message
                $content = json_decode($message->getMessageText());

                // Dispatch Email

                // Delete Job
                $this->deleteJob('emails', $message->getMessageId(), $message->getPopReceipt());
            }

            sleep(30);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are lines 180-200 of /SocketWrapper.php ??

Comment: @Yokhannan they're using a PEAR package (HTTP_Request2). I've created a gist with the lines you've requested: https://gist.github.com/fedeisas/5331164#file-socketwrapper-php-L175. Thanks1

Answer (score 1):

This looks like overload or timeout problem. PHP library can't write to Azure socket. Probably you exceeding Azure load limits with infinite loop `while(true) { ... }`.

Don't create `queueService` at each loop because you closing and opening pear socket infinitely.

Try moving line:

```
$this->queueRestProxy = $this->servicesBuilder->createQueueService($this->connectionString);
```

before `while(true) {` :

```
$this->write('Processing mails...');
$this->queueRestProxy = $this->servicesBuilder->createQueueService($this->connectionString);    
while(true) {
        // Get message.
```

If that doesn't help then probably `azure-sdk-for-php` library incorrectly uses a socket mechanism - create new issue at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php OR use this approach: [AzurePHP - Polling an Azure Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763515/azurephp-polling-an-azure-queue?rq=1)

Comment: That line you refer was there just for testing pursposes. I was trying to `reopen` the socket... The problem is that the socket dies if I don't make a request within 30 seconds. That's why I was trying to respawn the socket.

Comment: OK, so it's `azure-sdk-for-php` issue, `QueueService` should reopen socket on `listMessages` if required.